# How can I extend or change the behaviour of c++ standard library objects

Tags: c++, std

Let's say I want to change the default way the `std::bitset` prints out its bit. The normal way is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {

    std::cout << "size of int is: " << (sizeof (int)) << std::endl;

    std::bitset<32> bits = 0xFFFF0000;
    std::cout << "Original\n" << bits << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which rightfully outputs (assuming 32 bit processor):

```
size of int is: 4
Original
11111111111111110000000000000000
```

Now I want it to print the bits with a space between each byte: e.g.

```
11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000
```

or a hypen between each byte:

```
11111111-11111111-00000000-00000000
```

I know that a solution is to I make my own function to print bits. But I want to know how can I extend or add more functionality and options to a  standard library object.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can't modify a class after it has been defined and you are (generally) not allowed to add declarations to `std`.

Comment: @user17732522 you mean I can not subclass or inherit from std stuff?

Comment: Yes you can inherit from stuff in `std`, but you must do so outside of `std`.

Comment: Yes you can do that, just like you can with any user-defined class. But that seems like a trivial answer. What exactly is the problem you _don't_ know how to solve?

Comment: `operator <<` is not `virtual` anyway. You might write a wrapper around the class... There are no customization point for that display change.

Comment: There are several levels you can do it. Make your own print function, inherit your class from bitset, make your own cout/ostream class, which only reacts differently to certain streamed classes, create a prefix like `cout << modifier << bitset`, create your own standard library or C++ implementation altogether, patch things on the linker level, ... Should your way be standard compliant, compatible, portable?

Comment: Making your own function _is_ how you add functionality. The clue is in the name. Inheritance is for substitutability, except in special cases like CRTP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to know how can I extend or add more functionality and options to a standard library object.

Don't. At least not directly. In general you better do not overload operators for types you do not own. In this case there is already an  `std::ostream`s `<<` operator. Rather write your own custom type that manages how to print a `std::bitset`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

template<size_t N>
struct pretty_print_bitset {
    pretty_print_bitset(std::bitset<N>& ref,char sep) : ref(ref),sep(sep) {} // constructor for CTAD
    std::bitset<N>& ref;
    char sep;
};

template <size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const pretty_print_bitset<N>& ppb){
    for (int i=0;i<N;++i){
        out << ppb.ref[i];
        if ((i+1)%8 ==0 && i !=N-1) out << ppb.sep;
    }        
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::bitset<32> b;
    std::cout << pretty_print_bitset{b,'-'};
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/hs765TvvT):

```
00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000
```

Comment: This a great solution.  I learnet a lot thanks! just a side note, I think the loop should start from N and go down to 0

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you simply want to change the representation of the bitset when passing to an ostream. I.e you do not need to change any internal behavior of the bitset, nor access any internal data by other means than using the public API.

In this case you can simply overload the stream insertion operator:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

template < std::size_t T >
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::bitset<T>& v) 
{
    for(int i=T-1; i>=0; --i) {
        os << v[i];
        if(i%8 == 0) {
            os << " ";
        }
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "size of int is: " << (sizeof (int)) << std::endl;

    std::bitset<32> bits = 0xFFFF0000;
    std::cout << "Original\n" << bits << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is fine in a small example, but in a larger project you need to take care of other code that calls the operator (code that is not in your control), what namespace to place it, and ADL. In the worst case you'll end up needing to explicitly state which `operator` you want to call, yours or the one from std.

Comment: Thanks. Side not the condition inside the loops also need ` i != 0`

Comment: Defining template function without class/namespace that you own is dangerous. standard might implement that overload later ([it already did for the generic form](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2)), leading to ill-formed program NDR. And if others does the same, you will also have ill-formed program NDR too.